# Where to registerClass for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController`, which I allocate, initialize, and add to `self.view` in the `viewDidLoad` method. I am using 2 types of cells for the collection view, a subclassed one, and a standard `UICollectionViewCell`. Now everything works fine, and as intended. It's just that, the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` is called inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, right before `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. This means `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` is called **each** time a cell is dequeued. Seems redundant to me.

So I tried to move the register-class code to the `viewDidLoad` method itself, right after where the collection-view is initialized. Results in a crash with **must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard**. I then tried moving the code to the *end* of `viewDidLoad` after it has been added in `self.view`, still same crash. Then I moved the code to `viewWillAppear:`, and crash again.

It seems the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` can only be called from inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, and nowhere else.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this just how cells must be registered for collection views?

**NOTE:** There are no `XIBs` or storyboards. It's all done through coding. Also MRC, not ARC.

EDIT: Added code

Inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
photosCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, 320, height)
                                          collectionViewLayout:[[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init] autorelease]];

photosCollectionView.opaque = YES;

photosCollectionView.layer.opaque = YES;

photosCollectionView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;

photosCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xd3d7dc);

photosCollectionView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xd3d7dc).CGColor;

photosCollectionView.dataSource = self;

photosCollectionView.delegate = self;

photosCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0);

//other UI element init

[self.view addSubview:photosCollectionView];

[photosCollectionView release];


[photosCollectionView registerClass:[collectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AllPhotosCell"];//subclassed cell
```

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` (relevant code):

```
NSString* CellIdentifier = @"AllPhotosCell";

collectionCell *cell = [photosCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Show your *exact* code in viewDidLoad with registerClass:

Comment: Added relevant code.

Comment: Don't call registerClass inside cellForItemAtIndexPath. Do this in viewDidLoad. Must be failing there for another reason.

Comment: That's the working code. Show the non-working code (and test that it doesn't work). BTW: It's 2014, time to switch to ARC.

Comment: Why do you manually release it after adding it to the view ? This is likely causing the issue. Call registerClass: after you alloc/innit your collectionView: Also as @Eiko said, time to move to arc ?

Comment: The non working code, is simply when you move the `registerClass` method to, well, anywhere but `cellforItem...`.As for ARC, this is a minor part of a **huge** project. ARC was a pain in the neck in terms of memory management. Choosing MRC over ARCV solved has helped a lot.

Comment: @CW0007007 release should not cause issues, as it's retained by the view (and wouldn't work anyway if not).

Comment: The code to show is the non-working combination of viewDidLoad including registration and cellForItemAtIndexPath: that throws the error. And if you strip down your code, make sure it still shows the error. You cannot send your brother to the doctor to get your broken leg x-rayed.

Comment: Edited to generate exception.